# Reading the browser navigation bar and generating a navigational link based upon it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a script that can read the address bar;

example (not an actual link): http://www.example.net/page-2011

and take the page-2011 part and turn it into

```
« <a href="/page-2010">Previous</a>|<a href="/page-2012">Next</a> »
```

So instead of having to make 3000 navigation links it just generates it automatically. As an additional challange the sidebar is a completely separate page, which is loaded at "compile time" for lack of a better term, when you load the page. http://www.example.net/nav:side This is the actual page that's pulled every time a page loads.

Answer (score 0):

> The Window.location read-only property returns a Location object with information about the current location of the document.

[javascript Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

```
var url1 = window.location;            //returns the url as an object
var url2 = window.location.href;       //returns the url string
var url3 = window.location.pathname;   //returns the url path
```

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

[javascript .split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Once you have the URL, you can use `.split("-")`. In your case, if every page is set as `/page-2`, this will return an object `{"page","2"}`

```
var pathSplit = url3.split("-");       //returns {"page","2"} from page-2
```

> The slice() method extracts a section of a string and returns a new string.

[javascript .slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

In the event that your path ends with a `/`, you can use .slice() to trim off the last character.

```
var pathSplice = url3.slice(0,-1);     //returns /page-2 from /page-2/
var pathSplit = pathSplice.split("-"); //returns {"/page","2"} from /page-2
```

Now you can grab the page number `2` by accessing the `pathSplit` object at index `1` and then parse the page number `2` as an integer and perform the required equations to receive the desired pages.

```
var pageNum = parseInt(pathSplit[1]);
var prevPage = 0,
    nextPage = 0;
if(isNaN(pageNum) === false){
    prevPage = pageNum - 1;    //returns 1 from 2
    nextPage = pageNum + 1;    //returns 3 from 2
}
```

> [Element.setAttribute()]Sets the value of an attribute on the specified element. If the attribute already exists, the value is updated; otherwise a new attribute is added with the specified name and value.

[javascript .setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Finally, you can set the value of your anchors `<a></a>` like so

```
var prevLink = document.querySelector(".prev-link");
var nextLink = document.querySelector(".next-link");
prevLink.setAttribute("href", "/page-" + prevPage.toString());
nextLink.setAttribute("href", "/page-" + nextPage.toString());
```

**NOTE:** Ensure you have assigned a class or id to your previous and next page links.